# Static initialization of a struct with pointer to other, as-yet undeclared static variable

Tags: c, syntax

C syntax question.

I am looking to make a declaration something like the following:

```
struct thingy {
    struct thingy* pointer;
}

static struct thingy thing1 = {
    .pointer = &thing2
};

static struct thingy thing2 = {
    .pointer = &thing1
};
```

I have tried declaring and initializing separately, as in:

```
struct thingy {
    struct thingy* pointer;
}

static struct thingy thing1;
static struct thingy thing2;

thing1 = {
    .pointer = &thing2
};

thing2 = {
    .pointer = &thing1
};
```

However I am not sure whether I can declare and initialize static variables separately

Is there a way I can actually get these to point to each other from compilation?

Comment: This was a very nice first post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to "forward declare" (actually, this is a ***tentative definition***, thanks AndreyT!) the static instances first, and then initialize their definitions with the desired pointers.

```
static struct thingy thing1;
static struct thingy thing2;

static struct thingy thing1 = {
    .pointer = &thing2
};

static struct thingy thing2 = {
    .pointer = &thing1
};
```

Technically, you only need to <s>forward declare</s> tentatively define `thing2`.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that the type signature was to be repeated in the initialization. Is there a reason this goes for static variables but not variables that I've declared in (--is there a standard term for the scope of a variable declared in a block?--) automatic scope?

Comment: This is a special case because you wanted to initialize `thing1` with the address of `thing2`. In general you cannot refer to a identifier that has not yet been declared.

Comment: @jxh: Sorry, I was wrong. A definition without an initializer is a *tentative* definition, even when it is `static`. It is OK to have many definitions, as long as no more than one of them is non-tentative. (I thought that explicit `static` is enough to make it non-tentative, but it is not the case.)

Comment: @pen: Note that you cannot really *forward-declare* a *static* variable in C language. C has no syntax for that. However, C allows you to *define* the same variable several times (in the same file), as long as you ensure that only one definition has an initializer. The language feature is called *tentative definition* and it exists largely to resole problems as yours. (C++, BTW, does not support tentative definitions).

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for the info! I did not know that this was a thing.